# jQuery position function returns object, but accessing properties gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to use jQuery's position function, and logging the object it returns the proper value:

```
var pos = $('.myObject').position();
console.log(pos); //works, with proper left and top properties visible in console
```

However, when try to access the left or top position properties in the object, I get an 'undefined' error, which is very odd as I can see they are properly being stored in the object itself in the console.

```
var pos = $('.myObject').position();
console.log(pos.left); //doesn't work
```

The simplicity of this issue really has me stumped. Not sure exactly what is happening. This function is being called in a handler inside the jQuery waypoints function, but I doubt that makes a difference.

Edit: Full code below.

```
  $('.scrollPoint').waypoint({   
     handler: function(direction) {
         var app = $(this).attr('app');
         $('.activeApp').removeClass('activeApp');
         $('.app[appID='+app+']').addClass('activeApp');

         var posLeft = $('.activeApp').position();
         console.log(posLeft); // shows proper object position in console
         $('.appCaret').css("margin-left", posLeft.left+"px"); // error:'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'posLeft.left')
     }

    });
```

Comment: you probably have some typo there.. create some fiddle if you are unsure so we can assist you. You can also output that directly like this : console.log( $('.myObject').position().left );

Comment: please post your code in order to take a look at it ;)

Comment: `.position()` would only return `null` if the element doesn't exist / cannot be found.

Comment: @FelixKling position isn't actually returning null, which I confirmed by logging (and it shows accurate position data). Trying to access the left or top properties of that object, though, gives me undefined.

Comment: Oh, so `pos.left` *is* undefined, it does not *throw* an error? I assumed it threw an error because you mentioned "'undefined' error".

Comment: 1-make sure that **.myObject** element exists in the html. 2-make sure you are not overriding pos in your code before loging pos.left .

Comment: Oh no, `pos` itself is defined, and accessing it or logging it throws no errors and shows accurate data in the log. But both `pos.top` and `pos.left` throw an undefined error when accessed, which is weird as when logging the `pos` object both `left` and `top` are defined in the console

Comment: Fiddle the whole thing, otherwise it makes no sense. the code is correct.

Comment: @0_0 just checked, both of those conditions are met